# Store specific index value of output in R

Tags: r

I'm basically looking for the equivalent of the following python code in R:

```
df.groupby('Categorical')['Count'].count()[0]
```

The following is what I'm doing in R:

```
by(df$count,df$Categorical,sum)
```

This accomplishes the same thing as the first code but I'd like to know how to store an index value to a variable in R (new to R) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the `by` code, it seems like we can use (assuming that 'count' is a columns of 1s)

```
library(dplyr)
out <- df %>%
        group_by(Categorical) %>%
        summarise(Sum = sum(count))
```

---

If the columns 'count' have other values as well, the `python` function is taking the frequency count of 'Categorical' column.  So, a similar option would be

```
out <- df %>% 
        count(Categorical) %>%
        slice(1) %>%
        pull(n)
```

Comment: These are outputting tibbles. I'm looking for an integer output

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! Also, just curious what does '%>%' do exactly? Is it equivalent to '\n' in python?

Comment: @user10939484  It is a pipe operator, connecting the expression on the lhs with the rhs so that each output you get from the previous line is passed into the next line of code for more processing.  somewhat similar to dot notation in python (but not entirely

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the explanation and help!

Comment: If we look at the second set of code, `count(Categorical)` gives the frequency count of 'Categorical' on the dataset identifier (`df`) and that is info is passed with `%>%`, now we have a 2 column tbl_df/data.frame, `slice`, the first row of that dataset, and then `pull` the column 'n' to get a `vector`